# Since which version of C++ are default arguments allowed?

Tags: c++, c++11

Example:

```
void foo(int a,int b=12) {
...
}
```

Since which version of C++ is this legal? Was it introduced in C++11?

Comment: Since forever..

Comment: I guess I've been using C++ for too long. My first thought was "why do you even need to ask". But not an invalid question on the whole.

Comment: Since 1979's C with classes

Comment: Since before people answered questions in the comments section

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is legal in all standardized versions of C++, starting with C++98.

Comment: AFAIK, it should be legal even before the first C++ standard.

Comment: @AdrianTam Before it was standardized, the notion of code being "legal" is somewhat dubious, as that is usually used as shorthand for code being standard compliant.

Comment: To be honest, this _is_ kind of misleading, although I do understand where you're coming from with it.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit While discussions about the design and evolution of pre-standard C++ certainly are interesting, I feel like that is beside the point of the question. Especially the mention of C++11 suggests (to me) that official (as in standardized) versions of C++ are what is being asked for. That said, does the tweaked wording fix the ambiguity in your opinion?

Comment: It is no longer misleading. :) Though arguably it is not a full answer to the question ;) (I'm mostly nitpicking)

Comment: "While discussions about the design and evolution of pre-standard C++ certainly are interesting" – (OT) If this is intentional, [I see what you did there](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html); and on topic: I agree that "legal C++" didn't have a real meaning before '98, but Stroustrup's [other and more famous C++ book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C%2B%2B_Programming_Language) did serve as the de facto standard from 1985-1998.

Comment: @ArneVogel Heh, yeah, that was on purpose. :) Anyway, I don't think a debate about what can be considered "legal" pre-standard C++ is needed or helpful in the scope of this Q/A. As I read it, someone asking if a feature was introduced in C++11 is more interested in which standard(s) exactly provide it, and less about its way into the standard. Thus the succinct focus on standardized versions in my answer.

Answer (score 17):

Per Bjarne's ["History of C++"](http://www.stroustrup.com/hopl2.pdf) (see page 6), default arguments were added in the very first version of the very first incarnation of C++, *C With Classes*, whose "spec" (if you can call it that) was published back in 1980.

They remained present through to initial standardisation in 1998, and remain present to this day.

In other words, every version of C++ since the dawn of time has supported default arguments.

In other words: ***literally forever***. :)

Answer (score 5):

I started using C++ in 1991, and default arguments were present then in Borland C++ v3.0 and also in Stanley Lippman's book C++ Primer 2nd ed (also 1991). I imagine that qualifies as 'legal' - or it did at the time!